# ftp login info security

Tags: nautilus, password, 13.10

In Nautilus, when connecting to a remote server, you can select to remember your password  and username forever:

[image]

Is it safe to select this? With 'safe' I mean unrecoverable when my HDD get's mounted without knowing my personal password. The only thing encrypted (as far as I know) is my `/home` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password information like this (and WiFi passwords, browser passwords, etc.) are stored encrypted in a login keyring. The login keyring is encypted using your login password, and is decrypted when you log in.

If someone steals your hard drive, they would need your login password to decrypt the keyring. Additionally, the keyring is stored in your home folder, so if you have your home folder encrypted, then the keyring and its data are stored double encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Something worth mentioning is that ftp is a clear text protocol. So this password you want to keep safe on your computer is sent out to the network in clear text every time you log on to this ftp.

So if security is REALLY something you worry about you should use something else like sftp or perhaps ftps.

This  means if someone would steal your computer. They would only have to set up a new ftp   server with the same address, connect on your bookmarked ftp connection. Sniff the traffic to extract your username and password from the traffic.

Comment: at least you should not use this ftp username/password combination any place else